# TextSwither with CountDownTimer

Tags: android, animation, countdown

So, I want to display my timer in GUI with animation. To this end I used a TextSwitcher. But my TextSwitcher don't show anything! 
Maybe you know another way to do this?
Code from onCraeteView() method from fragment

```
    Context context = getActivity();
    textSwitcher = new TextSwitcher(context);

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    textSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
    textSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
    textSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        public View makeView() {               
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setLayoutParams(new TextSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            return textView;
        }
    });

    new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TextSwTextView = (TextView) textSwitcher.getChildAt(0);
            TextSwTextView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            ////
        }
    }.start();
```